# Searching word in vim?

Tags: vim

I can search word in vim with `/word`. How can I search only for `word`, excluding searches for `word1` and `word2`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding exact match in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147639/finding-exact-match-in-vim)

Answer (score 272, accepted):

like this:

```
/\<word\>
```

`\<` means beginning of a word, and `\>` means the end of a word,

Adding @Roe's comment:
VIM provides a shortcut for this.  If you already have *word* on screen and you want to find other instances of it, you can put the cursor on the word and press `'*'` to search forward in the file or `'#'` to search backwards.

Comment: placing your cursor over a word and pressing * (forward) or # (backward) is a shortcut

Comment: why is this beneficial vs just doing: /word

Comment: @semja: let's say you have a variable 'data' and its valid indication 'data_valid'.  If I want to search only for 'data' but not 'data_valid', then '/data' won't do the job.  I need to tell vim where to *stop* matching the pattern.

Comment: This fails in following example:
`1word1`
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22148017/2609994 for a solution.

Comment: Is there a `vim` configuration to make it search exact word without wrapping the search string with `\<` and `\<` characters?

Comment: @eigenfield, typing g* seems to do what you want http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#gstar

Comment: I know this should be the answer, but vim is ignoring it for me. It just acts as if I didn't add `/>` at the end. I am fairly sure this solution has worked for me in the past, too.

Comment: @felwithe, maybe it's a typo, but if not, you need to be aware that you used forward slash `/`. You should use backslash '\' at the end of you term. With `/\<word/>` (wrongly typing) you actually try to find words that start with `word`, so you will match `word`, `word_data`, `wordy`, and so on.

Answer (score 97):

1. vim filename
2. press /
3. type word which you want to search
4. press Enter

Comment: Could someone explain why this may have received down votes? Worked for me.

Comment: Because the OP asked to search specifically for `"word"`. The solution posted here basically does a search for `%word%`, whether its `thiswordisawesome` or `word56` or `26word`.

Comment: Also, because the OP explicitly stated that they know about the `/` command. As such, this answer is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 35):

If you are working in Ubuntu,follow the steps:

1. Press `/` and type word to search
2. To search in forward press 'SHIFT' key with  `*` key
3. To search in backward press 'SHIFT' key with `#` key

Comment: how can i highlight searched word?

Comment: @jorgesaraiva: 1st of all, you'll probably get an answer faster by asking a new question (rather than waiting for somebody to stumble upon this comment 3 months after you asked it).  2nd of all, you can do `:set hls` in Vim to highlight your search result.  To turn off highlighting do `:set nohls`

Comment: This really only works if the first result from doing `/word` is exactly `word` instead of `word.+`

Comment: this does not work for me on an AWS ubuntu 18.04 instance. 
using windows git-bash to ssh to the ubuntu server if that is relevant. 
weird.

Answer (score 34):

For basic searching:

- /pattern       - search forward for pattern
- ?pattern       - search backward
- n              - repeat forward search
- N              - repeat backward

Some variables you might want to set:

- :set ignorecase - case insensitive
- :set smartcase  - use case if any caps used
- :set incsearch  - show match as search

Comment: This isn't what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 2):

Basic search (once you have opened the file in `vim`) using `vim`:

-Hit `ESC` on your computer keyboard

-Hit the forward slash symbol on your keyboard `/`

-Type the word or symbol you intend to search; for example, to search for the term "rbmq" type `/rbmq`

-Hit `Enter`

-Hit **n** to search forward (moving towards the end of the file) and **N** to search backward  (moving towards the beginning of the file)

Comment: How does that answer the question? The OP already shows that they are aware of that. The question is how to ***avoid*** matches like `123rbmq123`...