# Find and replace whole words in vim

Tags: regex, vim, editor, replace

To find and replace all instances of a word in vim, I use

```
%s/word/newword/g
```

How do I change this so that it only finds instances of "word" that are whole words?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Searching word in vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458915/searching-word-in-vim)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can use `\<` to match the beginning of a word and `\>` to match the end:

```
%s/\<word\>/newword/g
```

Comment: That works.  Is that a regex syntax, or does that only work in vim?

Comment: It is a Vim specific regexp syntax. Perl (PCRE) for example uses \b...\b instead.

Comment: It's a pity that Vim doesn't support \b...\b

Comment: You can use PRCE expressions in Vim by accessing perl with the "perldo" command. :perldo s/\bword/newword/g

Comment: Is there any short cut for quickly input `\<` and `\>` ?

Comment: @pplorins Use the [magic star](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#star) to search for the whole word first, then drop the whole-word search pattern into the command line by typing `:%s/<Ctrl-R>/`

Answer (score 20):

For case-sensitive replace.. you can use "\C"

```
:%s/\<word\>\C/newword/g
```

It replaces only "word" with newword leaving others like Word,WORD... unreplaced.

Comment: why is \C required, when it can be simply done using,
:%s/\<word\>/newword/g.
Would u pls highlight the importance of using \C

Comment: \C is needed only if we want case-sensitive search.

Comment: You're probably better to use the `i` ignorecase or `I` don't-ignorecase [flags](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3As_flags), eg. `:%s/\<word\>/newword/gI`

Answer (score 1):

For PCRE compatible search and replace, you can use the `perldo` or `rubydo` commands as described here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Perl_compatible_regular_expressions

For example:

```
:perldo s/\bword\b/newword/g
```