# Finding exact match in vim

Tags: vim

Using `/` or `?` enables to find a match for a word in vim. But how can I find an exact match?
For example, my text contains the following words: `a aa aaa aaaa aa` and I type `/aa` This will find all the strings containing the pattern aa, but what if I want to find exactly `aa` and not `aaaa aaaa`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To find a single, standalone `aa` (not `a`, `aaa`, ...), you need to assert no match of that character both before and afterwards. This is done with negative *lookbehind* (`\@<!` in Vim's regular expression syntax) and *lookahead* (`\@!`) enclosing the match itself (`a\{2}`):

```
/\%(a\)\@<!a\{2}\%(a\)\@!/
```

#### Simplification

Those assertions are hard to type, if the border around the match is also a *non-keyword* / *keyword* border, you can use the shorter `\<\a\{2}\>` assertions (as in LSchueler's answer), but this doesn't work in the general case, e.g. with `xaax`.

Comment: I would use `aa` instead of `a\{2}`.  Since `a` is already a (literal) atom, I would dispense with the grouping characters:  `/a\@<!aaa\@<!/`.  Looking at that deceptive `aaa` I might decide that `a\{2}` is clearer after all.

Answer (score 47):

You enclose the string you are looking for by `\<` and `\>` like in `/\<aa\>` to match exactly that string.

Comment: That only works when there's also a keyword border; it will fail for example to find the match in `xaax`.

Comment: Wow, I wasn't aware of that! For your example the keys `*` and `#` don't work either.

Answer (score 2):

You can search for `aa[^a]`, which will find your two `a`s and nothing else.

EDIT: oh boy, y'all are after an *exact* match :-) So, to match exactly two `aa`s and nothing else:

```
[^a]\zsaa\ze[^a]\|^\zsaa\ze$\|^\zsaa\ze[^a]\|[^a]\zsaa\ze$
```

And the branches expanded out:

```
  [^a]\zsaa\ze[^a]
\|^\zsaa\ze$
\|^\zsaa\ze[^a]
\|[^a]\zsaa\ze$
```

These cover all contingencies--the `aa`s can be at the beginning, the middle, or the end of any line. And there can't be more than two `a`s together.

- `\zs` means the actual match starts here
- `\ze` means the actual match ends here
- the first branch finds `aa` in a line surrounded by other characters
- the second branch finds `aa` when it makes up the *whole* line
- the third branch finds `aa` at the beginning of a line
- and the fourth branch finds `aa` at the end of a line.

My mind boggles at fancy things like look-behind assertions, so I tried to stick to reasonably simple regex concepts.

EDIT 2: see @benjifisher's simplified, more elegant version [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147639/finding-exact-match-in-vim/22147738?noredirect=1#comment33632285_22147738) for your intellectual pleasure.

Comment: This will also match `aa` at the end of `aaaa` and `aaa`, so I am giving +1 to @MosteM's answer.

Comment: And it won't work when there's no character following, e.g. at the end of the line.

Comment: This is getting to be fun!  First of all, the constructions `^\zs` and `\ze$` are more complicated than necessary:  you get the same results with `^` and `$`.  Second of all, I think you save a few characters with `\(^\|[^a]\)\zsaa\ze\([^a]\|$\)`.  Decide for yourself whether shorter is easier to read in this case.

Comment: @benjifisher - I bow to your superior intellect. Your shortened version does work as advertised. I'll leave my last regex as is because it gets the job done too and is a good starting point for thinking about this. But am putting in a pointer to your comment too.

Answer (score 2):

This simple one helped me to match the exact pattern. You can try this.

```
\V\c\<pattern_here\>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bring your cursor to exact word which you want to search.

Press *  (Either Shitf+8  or from numpad of keybord).

Comment: This is very handy, but paradoxically it relies on first finding at least one instance of the string you are trying to find. Awesome for quickly locating duplicates, though!